# Roof loaded with shingles over ridge - should I demand they be replaced?

Tags: roof, roofing

So I know that when a roof is loaded with architectural shingles prior to installation, you're not supposed to lay them over the ridge, but instead lay they remain flat and use toekick boards to prevent them from sliding off. ([Not laying over ridge](http://www.owenscorning.com/NetworkShare/Roofing/10014283-TruDefinition%C2%AE-Duration%C2%AE-Series-Shingles-Installation-Instructions.pdf) is a precaution on page 1 of the install instructions for my shingles.)

I made certain with my roofer that this would be done. The delivery crew arrived with toeboards, started, and I could hear them being hammered in. Great.

Went out when they were done to find that they made a "judgment call" to lay half the shingles over the ridges. [image: Shingles over ridges]

Should I demand replacement?

Comment: Not an expert, so just a comment: I don't see why this would be a problem. It is pretty standard practice in my area (Maryland) - pretty sure my last two roof replacements had the shingles on the ridge with no ill effects. Especially if (as is typical) the shingles only sit there for 1 day.

Comment: Apparently the architectural laminated shingles can be easily damage when bent over a ridge.  I would be calling the roofer and have him chew out the delivery company.  Owens Corning would no doubt void warranty if this was shown to them.  Plus that is 1500 lbs on that left portion of ridge  probably more weight than it is designed to hold I don’t approve of roof top delivery since it is a risk of damage to structure and product.

Answer (score 2):

At minimum I'd review the manufacturer's installation instructions and warranty terms applicable to the specific shingle that was installed. It would seem normal that the warranty will be affected if instructions are violated. If you find that the installer or his supplier's delivery crew violated the instructions and jeopardized the warranty, you should consider how you'd want to be compensated.

Maybe you'd want the shingles replaced (but how to know which are the affected shingles?), cash to compensate for the damage done to the manufacturer warranty, or some other restitution.

It must be a regional thing -- I'm no professional roofer, but I've seen bundles of shingles stacked on lots of roofs and *never once* have I seen them folded over the ridge like that.

Comment: Talked to the roofing supervisor who assured me that there shouldn't be damage b/c it wasn't cold, and that if there was anything visible they'd get new bundles. He was convincing, but it's still irksome when the directions literally say not to do that.

Comment: Agree there must be some regionality to it. Just to see, I googled another well-reviewed roofer in the area, and found a picture of them reroofing on their website. All bundles over the ridge. :P